# zephyr west -t menuconfig fail

Tags: zephyr-rtos

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD6sw.png)

I am test i.mxrt1060 fo menuconfig, the command is:

west build -b mimxrt1060_evk -t menuconfig --build-dir rt-1064/hello samples/hello_world

But it failed. How can I solve it。

I want to be able to use menuconfig normally

Comment: Do not add images of text. Add the relevant logs straight to the post.